# How can I add Localhost\Users + READ permissions to a folder in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, permissions

I tried:

```
$Folderpath='D:\DATA\'
$user_account='USERS'
$Acl = Get-Acl $Folderpath
$Ar = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($user_account, "Read", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.Setaccessrule($Ar)
Set-Acl $Folderpath $Acl
```

I get following error:

> Set-Acl : The security identifier is not allowed to be the owner of this object.

I do not want USERS to be the owner tho, only to have READ.

Comment: I do not believe the issue is with your script, but the ownership already on that Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [File System Security PowerShell Module](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/1abd77a5-9c0b-4a2b-acef-90dbb2b84e85) this task becomes much easier as you can use `Add-NTFSAccess`, which acts in a much more logical manner:

```
Add-NTFSAccess -Path D:\DATA -Account 'LocalComputerName\Username' -AccessRights Read
```

And if it's a Domain Group just replace `LocalComputerName` with the Domain Name.